# Loading NYS ALL Voters (Voter File) into BigQuery crashes

Tags: google-bigquery

Thanks for Big Query.

When trying to load the NYS Voter File into Big Query we see this:

The file is

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fedex1 fedex1 5.3G Jun  3 06:43 AllNYSVoters.txt
```

Is 5.3  Gigs too large to load from the command line?

It is only 15,486,253 rows  (15 Million rows)

It appears stackoverflow does not like code only questions, so I am giving more details.

```
> You have encountered a bug in the BigQuery CLI. Google engineers
> monitor and answer questions on Stack Overflow, with the tag
> google-bigquery:
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery Please
> include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as
> well as the following information:
> 
> ========================================
> == Platform ==   CPython:2.7.3:Linux-3.8.11-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
> == bq version ==
>   2.0.21
> == Command line ==   ['/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py',
> '--credential_file',
> '/home/x1/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/x7/singlestore.json',
> '--project', 'personal-real-estate', 'load', 'nys.all_voter_file',
> 'AllNYSVoters.txt',
> 'LASTNAME:string,FIRSTNAME:string,MIDDLENAME:string,NAMESUFFIX:string,RADDNUMBER:string,RHALFCODE:string,RAPARTMENT:string,RPREDIRECTION:string,RSTREETNAME:string,RPOSTDIRECTION:string,RCITY:string,RZIP5:string,RZIP4:string,MAILADD1:string,MAILADD2:string,MAILADD3:string,MAILADD4:string,DOB:string,GENDER:string,ENROLLMENT:string,OTHERPARTY:string,COUNTYCODE:integer,ED:integer,LD:integer,TOWNCITY:string,WARD:string,CD:integer,SD:integer,AD:integer,LASTVOTEDDATE:timestamp,PREVYEARVOTED:string,PREVCOUNTY:string,PREVADDRESS:string,PREVNAME:string,COUNTYVRNUMBER:string,REGDATE:timestamp,VRSOURCE:string,IDREQUIRED:string,IDMET:string,STATUS:string,REASONCODE:string,INACT_DATE:timestamp,PURGE_DATE:timestamp,SBOEID:string,VoterHistory:string']
> == UTC timestamp ==   2014-06-11 11:42:34
> == Error trace ==   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py",
> line 806, in RunSafely
>     return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bq.py",
> line 1047, in RunWithArgs
>     job = client.Load(table_reference, source, schema=schema, **opts)   File
> "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py",
> line 2045, in Load
>     upload_file=upload_file, **kwds)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py",
> line 1642, in ExecuteJob
>     job_id=job_id)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py",
> line 1627, in RunJobSynchronously
>     upload_file=upload_file, job_id=job_id)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py",
> line 1535, in StartJob
>     projectId=project_id).execute()   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py",
> line 308, in execute
>     return super(BigqueryHttp, self).execute(**kwds)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/util.py",
> line 132, in positional_wrapper
>     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/apiclient/http.py",
> line 688, in execute
>     _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http, num_retries=num_retries)   File
> "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/util.py",
> line 132, in positional_wrapper
>     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/apiclient/http.py",
> line 867, in next_chunk
>     headers=headers)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/util.py",
> line 132, in positional_wrapper
>     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/oauth2client/client.py",
> line 490, in new_request
>     redirections, connection_type)   File "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/httplib2/__init__.py",
> line 1586, in request
>     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)   File
> "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/httplib2/__init__.py",
> line 1333, in _request
>     (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)   File
> "/var/host/media/removable/USB_Drive/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/httplib2/__init__.py",
> line 1289, in _conn_request
>     response = conn.getresponse()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
>     response.begin()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
>     version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
>     line = self.fp.readline()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 430, in readline
>     data = recv(1)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
>     return self.read(buflen)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
>     return self._sslobj.read(len)
> ========================================
> 
> Unexpected exception in load operation: [Errno 104] Connection reset
> by peer
```

Comment: where can I download NYS from?

Comment: Hi Felipe, if you are asking where the data came from. You can go to http://www.elections.ny.gov/FoilRequestVoterRegData.html and request all NYS voter file data.  They will mail a CD to you in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the log seems to show what the problem was:

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Was there any interruption in the network connectivity?

Comment: Hi Felipe, it probably is a connectivity issue.  So I'm uploading via google cloud storage first and I will try it that way.  Thanks, Ralph